# Issues with log in screen in IE 11

Tags: authentication, internet-explorer-11

I work for a credit union and we have a website where our participants that are invested in our loans can view their loan documents and reports. We have one participant that is trying to log into the website using IE 11 but it keeps looping her back to the log in screen and erases her username. A couple of things you should know: 
-it never brings her to the screen where she would enter her password
-I had her add the website to the Compatibility View settings area 
Do you have any ideas of what could be causing this looping effect? I apologize if this is a simple question/answer, but escalating this through our IT department would take too long and she really needs to get logged in.

Thanks for any help you can give me on this one.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the site is losing her login information. Is the server using ASP.NET? If so you need to update that software. See http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IE10AndIE11AndWindows81AndDoPostBack.aspx

If that's not it, there must be some specific issue with the code on the site. If IE10 works fine you can add a tag to the pages to make IE11 identify itself as IE10, `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">` .